# Using functions Phonegap in the webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins

I have developed a phonegap application using the concept of webview (developing a website). Then, I used many functions through Phonegap plugins to open PDF file in index.js and I succeeded to do that. But I want to call this function after opening my website through the application (as a webview), it doesn't call the function which open this PDF and I don't know how I should doing.

To make the problem easier, how can I call any JavaScript function defined in the body of the application in my webview?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'opening my website through the application'? Are you trying to open a web browser from your android app by event firing? or are you trying to use inappbrowser plugin or iframe?

Comment: @Hgoon  I am trying to invoke file download plugin from my website. I must use inappbrowser plugin to open my website(as a webview in my application) and attach some event to invoke my plugin. How can i communicate between the webview and the native application to execute some plugins?I see this documentation http://www.telerik.com/blogs/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser#disqus_thread but it seems about only passing data between the webview and the application!

Comment: Yes, as you said, data can be passed only within the app. I guess what you need is to deal with both client and server sides. Just like email sending examples using php / python.